# Como fazer um update via linked server sem usar join / relacionamento?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou precisando usar os dados de mais de uma tabela no mesmo select sem precisar fazer `JOIN` / relacionamento (quero setar um valor de uma tabela para outra através de um *linked server*).

Tentei o seguinte sem sucesso, pois não existe relacionamento entre as tabelas:

```
UPDATE tabelaA 
SET tabelaA.campoA = tabelaB.campoB 
FROM OPENQUERY([LINKEDSERVER], 'SELECT campoX, campoA FROM [baseA].[schema].[tabelaA]') 
INNER JOIN [baseB].[dbo].[tabelaB] ON tabelaA.Id = tabelaB.Id
WHERE tabelaA.Id = xxxx AND tabelaB.Id = aaaa AND tabelaB.outrocampo = 'Block'
```

Alguém teria um exemplo de como fazer isso no SQL Server?

Comment: Se você não fizer um relacionamento, como saberá qual registro se relaciona a que? Fora que você não explicou qual o problema que tenta resolver com isso.

Comment: Estou especificando os registros através das condições do WHERE, em ambas as tabelas. O meu problema é que tenho um valor na tabela A e outro na tabela B, que está em outro servidor, e eu preciso setar esse valor da tabela A para a tabela B. É um update de um campo apenas.

Answer (score 1):

Quando se utiliza vinculação de servidores é necessário ficar atento a reduzir o tráfego entre servidores. No código sql que postou é utilizada a função OPENQUERY e nesse caso sugiro que implemente o filtro no código sql que é enviado ao servidor remoto:

```
-- código #1
UPDATE A 
  SET campoA = B.campoB 
  FROM OPENQUERY([LINKEDSERVER], 
                 'SELECT Id, campoX, campoA FROM [baseA].[schema].[tabelaA] where Id=xxxx') as A
       INNER JOIN [baseB].[dbo].[tabelaB] as B ON A.Id = B.Id
  WHERE B.Id = aaaa AND B.outrocampo = 'Block';
```

Da forma acima o servidor remoto envia para o servidor local somente as linhas que atendam ao filtro (cláusula WHERE), o que reduz o tráfego de dados na rede.

---

Há a opção de utilizar identificador de 4 partes, em que o código sql seria alterado para

```
-- código #2
UPDATE A 
  set campoA = B.campoB 
  from [LINKEDSERVER].[baseA].[schema].[tabelaA] as A 
       inner join [baseB].[dbo].[tabelaB] as B ON A.Id = B.Id
  where A.Id = xxxx 
        and B.Id = aaaa 
        and B.outrocampo = 'Block';
```

No artigo [Programação e otimização de consultas distribuídas](https://portosql.wordpress.com/2019/06/30/linked-server/) você encontra os cuidados necessários para quando se programa consultas distribuídas. Fique atento às estatísticas de distribuição, conforme o documento “[Requisitos de estatísticas de distribuição para provedores OLE DB](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186237(v%3Dsql.105))”.

Atenção especial na definição de segurança na vinculação entre as instâncias.

---

Considerando-se que não há o relacionamento entre colunas, e que seja selecionada uma única linha da tabela B através de filtro na cláusula WHERE, então pode ser simplificado para:

```
-- código #3
declare @campoB xxx;
SELECT @campoB= B.campoB
  from [baseB].[dbo].[tabelaB] as B
  where B.Id = aaaa 
        and B.outrocampo = 'Block';

UPDATE A 
  set campoA = @campoB 
  from [LINKEDSERVER].[baseA].[schema].[tabelaA] as A
  where A.Id = xxxx;
```

Ou ainda:

```
-- código #2 v2
UPDATE A 
  set campoA = B.campoB 
  from [LINKEDSERVER].[baseA].[schema].[tabelaA] as A 
       cross join [baseB].[dbo].[tabelaB] as B
  where A.Id = xxxx 
        and B.Id = aaaa 
        and B.outrocampo = 'Block';
```

Comment: Agradeço as dicas, José. Mas nesse caso, não existe relacionamento entre as tabelas. A minha questão é: posso fazer esse update via openquery (ou outra forma que vincule tabelas de servidores diferentes) sem ter um relacionamento entre as tabelas (sem "join")? Como ficaria?

Comment: Sim, vide código #2 v2 e código #3.